# Rhinomocks stub method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, stub

Is it possible to stub out 1 method much like shimming in Microsoft Fakes?

In this case I would like to stub the DB call, but continue with the rest of my method logic.

```
public class Network
{
    public string GetUsers()
    {
       User users = GetUsersFromDB();
       return users.Formatted();
    }
```

Test:

```
Network network = MockRepositiory.GenerateStub<Network>();

network.Stub(x => x.GetUsersFromDB()).Return(myTestUserObject);

string result = network.GetUsers();

Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the reason why you are failing to setup stub for `GetUsersFromDB()` is that this method is not virtual or not public.
So you can made it `public virtual` and setup the stub.

But it is probably much better if you adjust the class according to [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and extract DB access code into a separate class with some interface like `IDbAccess`, e.g.

```
interface IDbAccess
{
    User GetUsersFromDB();
}
```

Then you can [inject interface as a dependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921152.aspx) into `Network` class and use it there instead of use DB access method member.
As a result, for test purpose you may just stub injected interface `IDbAccess` and run tests with no need to generate stubs for tested class, i.e. `Network`.